# Pantheon misbehaves after boot

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel, system, graphic-drivers, window-management

I installed elementary Freya yesterday and I encountered a weird bug after rebooting. I'll try to explain it as best as I can.

When I log into my session, the windows do not behave properly :

- I can't click on any of the buttons, in all windows
- I can't get focus on another window by clicking on it
- I can't access the top bar (with the clock and the notification widgets) or launch an app from the dock if another window is open
- Keyboard shortcuts seem to work (Alt-Tab, Tab to navigate in a window...)
- After I log out (with Ctrl+Alt+Del) and log in again, everything works perfectly.

It seems to be a graphical issue, which is why I tried installing the NVidia proprietary drivers, but the problem persisted.

Some info on my config:
[image: My config]

Cheers,

Clément

Comment: I too faced same issue in starting days after installation, but after few days the problem disappeared :)

Comment: Do you have any idea about what may have solved it ?

Comment: sorry, nope. I think automatically solved in my case. But suggest you run `updates` =)

Comment: You mention in the first sentence it only happened after a reboot. Does this mean you turned on the computer normally, and the shell is fine? But after warm restart it misbehaved?

Comment: The problem happens when I login for the first time after a boot (reboot or shutdown+boot). 
In the first sentence I meant that I did not notice the problem when I rebooted for the first time after installing elementary, but only in the subsequent boots.